# the resolution of my model is too high

Tags: animation, mesh, uv, multiresolution

I made a model of an animal in the blender. I started by doing the geometry and then applied the modifier multiresolution to be able to later sculpted. At this moment the mesh has almost 8000 vertices, but the faces are not properly organized. What I wanted exactly was a way to restructure the mesh so that the model can be used in animation easily, but without losing quality. Retopology is an option?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am having trouble picturing what your problem is... Do you think you could add a screenshot? To take a screenshot on a Windows 10 device, hold down Ctrl+PrtSc. To take a screenshot on any device running MacOS, hold down Shift+Command+4.

Comment: @YusaMac205 the images

Comment: 24 million vertices... that is a lot... Even 8 million is too many... you are going to have a very hard trying to rig that. Never apply a modifier unless you have a good reason to. Explore the Decimate modifier, it will allow you to work on vertex groups. Think hard on baking normals and using a low poly version if you want to rig and animate.

Comment: @YusaMac205 What if I'm a retopology? I do not have better results?

Comment: By all means. Creating a lower poly version will allow you to focus on getting topology that is better suited for rigging and animation. The art of 3D is optimization. Again, use the large model to bake a normal map to be used in the lower res model, so that you are faking the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best (and proper) way is to retopologize the model (use snaping on face) with subsurface-workflow and adding the detail by baking a normalmap with the highpoly model.

Then you'll get a animatable mesh with fast rendering details.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want your mesh to be simplified, you can use the decimate modifier and change the amount of total faces without modifying the shape too much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and then select "Un-Subdivide". This will reduce the number of vertices on your model by a lot.